# newgrp equivalent in Windows?

Tags: linux, permissions, windows

Is there a [newgrp](http://linuxers.org/article/difference-between-primary-and-secondary-groups-linux) equivalent in Windows?

Or is everybody just in the groups that their in and there is concept of primary and secondary groups?

Answer (score 3):

Users in windows can be in as many groups as you want, the only predence is that `Deny` permissions settings override an equivalent `Allow`.

You're going to have fun with permission inheritance too.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows groups don't really own files, with the exception of files created by users in the Administrators/Domain Admins.  Files are owned by users.  Everything else about file access is controled by the entries in the Access Control Lists (ACLs).

See: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961992.aspx.

> By default, a new object's owner is the security principal identified as the default owner in the access token attached to the creating process. When an object is created, the SID stored in the access token's Owner field is copied to the security descriptor's Owner field. The default owner is normally an individual—the user who is currently logged on. The only exceptions occur when the user is a member of either the Administrators group or the Domain Admins group.

The newgrp command is primarily used to set the group that owns files that you create under Linux.  This is because the old POSIX permissions system is relatively simplistic.  When a group of users need access to a file, that group owner needs to be used when files are being created.

Of course on Linux and other *nix you switch over to using Posix ACLs, in which case the group that owns an object may not matter that much and you don't need to worry about newgrp.  You can set an entry in an a directory's ACL that controls what happens when new files are created.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of Primary and Secondary Groups does not exist in Windows. Active Directory does provide an option to select primary and secondary groups for compatibility with unix OS's, but otherwise does not exist in an Active Directory environment.